# Can't get vertical layout group with scrolling working

Tags: unity-game-engine, layout, vertical-scrolling

I've got a panel which sits above my canvas and slides out upon clicking a button. I want to populate this panel with several objects (the number will be determined at runtime). Since the number of objects can exceed the number that would reasonably fit on a single row of the panel, I'd like to be able to scroll down with the mouse to new rows where the remaining objects have been populated.

To achieve this I've put a `Scroll Rect` and a `Mask` on the panel, created a child `Image` with a `Vertical Layout Group` to hold a series of child panels representing the rows that would hold the objects, and set the `Image` as the Content of the `Scroll Rect`.

The issue is that when I try to make one of the row panels a child of the `Image` object by dragging it to the `Image` in the Hierarchy, the anchors for the panel coalesce to a single point (the top left of the `Image` since it is set to Upper Left alignment) and when I try to manually drag the anchors to the appropriate position a box with a red X in it appears and expands in a manner that doesn't seem to correspond to the direction of the mouse.

Is this the right approach, and if so, how can I get this to work?

Thanks!